# Using Rust's errors inside a `loop` results in cheap blocking, but why?

Tags: rust

```
use std::io::ErrorKind;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let address = "localhost:7000";

    loop {
        match TcpStream::connect(address.clone()) {
            Err(err) => { match err.kind() {
                ErrorKind::ConnectionRefused => { continue; },
                kind => panic!("Error occurred: {:?}", kind),
            }; },
            Ok(_stream) => { /* do some stuff here */ },
        }
    }
}
```

Consider the piece of Rust code above. What's interesting to me here is not the `Ok` branch, but rather the `ErrorKind::ConnectionRefused` sub-branch coupled with the `loop`: it's very cheap, CPU-wise, consuming less than 1% CPU. This is great, it's what I want.

But I don't understand **why** it is cheap: comparable code in C would likely consume 100% basically **NOP**ing (not precisely but close enough).
Can anyone help me understand why this is so cheap?

Comment: Maybe `connect` is not so fast?

Comment: It's blazingly fast, when I do connect to another socket (i.e. by starting my accompanying server) it blows through my 10-iteration loop in less time than I can blink my eyes :)

Comment: What's the actual `address` value? I suspect that `TcpStream::connect` waits for the DNS resolver.

Comment: `address` is a `&'static str` containing `localhost:7000`, and is consumed as an owned `net::ToSocketAddrs` instance by the `connect` fn. Hence the clone: a borrow won't do.

Comment: Passing a `&'static str` to `connect` works just fine. `str` implements `ToSocketAddrs`, and for each `T` where `T: ToSocketAddrs + ?Sized`, `&'a T` implements `ToSocketAddrs`, therefore `&'a str` implements `ToSocketAddrs` too. I doubt this has anything to do with the question, though.

Comment: I am unable to produce a C program that "consume[s] 100% [of the CPU]". [Here is what I created](https://gist.github.com/shepmaster/8ffa98d5c30b02c4f770b58b47679fdc), but I'm certain it's incorrect (or at least very sloppy). Please [edit] your question to allow us to reproduce the slow and fast case in order to help you tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely that connect() is the culprit; in order to receive the *Connection refused* error, it first needs to look up the address (which should be cheap for localhost), then connect, and wait for the *Connection refused* response.

While localhost is certainly quite fast as opposed to remote network services, there's still a lot of overhead.

*ping localhost* has a latency of around 0.9ms for me. That means that your loop only does on the order of 1000 to 10000 iterations per second, which is not very much compared to an actual *while true {}* loop.